# Started container with docker run, now it is not showing up in docker ps -a

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I started a docker container with docker run, like this:

```
docker run \
-d \
--name plex \
--restart unless-stopped \
--network=host \
-e TZ="<timezone>" \
-e PLEX_CLAIM="<claimToken>" \
-v <path/to/plex/database>:/config \
-v <path/to/transcode/temp>:/transcode \
-v <path/to/media>:/data \
plexinc/pms-docker
```

[Link to GitHub.com/plexinc/pms-docker](https://github.com/plexinc/pms-docker)

The docker container is **running**, as Im able to access the port and service, but I can't seem to list the container when Im running `sudo docker ps -a` or `sudo docker ps -aq` or `sudo docker ps --filter "name=plex"`

I tried to run pstree, and got this output:

```
systemd─┬─accounts-daemon───2*[{accounts-daemon}]
        ├─agetty
        ├─atd
        ├─containerd───14*[{containerd}]
        ├─cron
        ├─dbus-daemon
        ├─dockerd─┬─docker-containe─┬─docker-containe─┬─s6-svscan─┬─s6-supervise
        │         │                 │                 │           └─s6-supervise───python───{python}
        │         │                 │                 └─9*[{docker-containe}]
        │         │                 └─17*[{docker-containe}]
        │         ├─docker-proxy───6*[{docker-proxy}]
        │         └─21*[{dockerd}]
        ├─dockerd─┬─containerd─┬─containerd-shim─┬─s6-svscan─┬─s6-supervise
        │         │            │                 │           └─s6-supervise───sh───Plex Media Serv─┬─Plex DLNA Serve───16*[{Plex DLNA Serve}]
        │         │            │                 │                                                 ├─Plex Script Hos───13*[{Plex Script Hos}]
        │         │            │                 │                                                 ├─Plex Script Hos───9*[{Plex Script Hos}]
        │         │            │                 │                                                 ├─Plex Tuner Serv───10*[{Plex Tuner Serv}]
        │         │            │                 │                                                 └─28*[{Plex Media Serv}]
        │         │            │                 └─9*[{containerd-shim}]
        │         │            └─17*[{containerd}]
        │         └─20*[{dockerd}]
```

So it is clearly running in docker. How do I restart or rebuild this container when I can't seem to get the ID from docker ps -a? `sudo docker stop plex` or `sudo docker restart plex` does not work either.

## Edit:

Sorry, did not include os and docker. Im running on Ubuntu server Ubuntu 18.10 (GNU/Linux 4.18.0-15-generic x86_64)

Docker version 18.09.1, build 4c52b90

## Edit 2:

`sudo ps aux |grep lex` output:

```
root      2392  0.0  0.0    196     4 ?        S    17:53   0:00 s6-supervise plex
HOMEUSER     2394  0.0  0.0   4504   752 ?        Ss   17:53   0:00 /bin/sh -c LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/plexmediaserver:/usr/lib/plexmediaserver/lib /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex\ Media\ Server
HOMEUSER     2402  1.6  0.5 707684 91316 ?        Sl   17:53   2:47 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Media Server
HOMEUSER     2458  0.1  0.3 1791280 55380 ?       SNl  17:53   0:17 Plex Plug-in [com.plexapp.system] /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-cc260c476/Framework.bundle/Contents/Resources/Versions/2/Python/bootstrap.py --server-version 1.14.1.5488-cc260c476 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Plug-ins-cc260c476/System.bundle
HOMEUSER     3134  0.2  0.1 373108 22540 ?        Sl   17:53   0:22 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex DLNA Server
HOMEUSER     3137  0.0  0.0 372964 15276 ?        Sl   17:53   0:00 /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Plex Tuner Service /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Tuner/Private /usr/lib/plexmediaserver/Resources/Tuner/Shared 1.14.1.5488-cc260c476 32600 /waitmutex
HOMEUSER     6382  0.0  0.0   7980   896 pts/1    S+   20:45   0:00 grep --color=auto lex
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo docker ps -aq`?
Try it and tell us.

Comment: Can you check again with `docker ps |grep lex` (no `-a` needed), `ps aux |grep lex`? It looks very strange for me

Comment: `systemd` means that you using `linux` at least. Maybe more information about OS, kernel, docker version will be useful

Comment: You should be able to use `plex` (the container's `--name`) to control the container in general.  If its behavior is confusing, starting it without `-d` ("in the background") and seeing what happens is often informative too.

Comment: Nope, sudo docker stop plex (or without sudo) does not work `Error response from daemon: No such container: plex` And if that would work, the container should be listed when doing docker ps.

Added information about OS and Docker version.

Comment: It sounds an awful lot like your container isn't running.  I don't know what's showing up in that `pstree` output.  I could believe your new container isn't starting because there's an old container claiming the same network resources and you've disabled all network isolation; do you actually need `--net host`?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can confirm the docker-container is running! This is so weird! Yes, I need network to get it to set up the service this way. I linked to the github page with more info.

Comment: @Garreth00 Add the last check `docker ps |grep lex`. I suppose we will see there plexmediaserver too

Comment: What do you see with `docker ps --filter "name=plex"`?

Comment: I only see headers, and no output. Tried the same command with a container name I see in the list with ps -a and get an output with ID, so the command works, only there is no container matching plex. Thank you for trying to help btw!

Comment: Pls check env variables `printenv | grep ^DOCKER`. Maybe they are configured and your docker client is connecting to some another daemon. Try also query docker API directly: `curl --silent --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock http/containers/json | jq .[].Names | grep plex`

Comment: There is nothing about docker when I do `sudo printenv`. Tried the `curl` command. The output does not contain the plex container, only another container I started with docker-compse. (and yes, I have double-checked that the docker-compose does not include the plex container/image)

Comment: Don't focus on the `plex` name, but try to search container ID returned from `docker run ...` command. Do you have any custom config for docker daemon?

Comment: I ran the `docker run` command three months ago, I did not take note of the ID the container at the time. Sorry. No I do not have any custom configure for the docker daemon.

Comment: Then try to find container by process PID. List all container processes: `docker ps -q | xargs docker top` or only main process `docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}, {{.Name}}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had installed docker twice. Once with `apt-get` and once with `snap`.

Completely removed docker, both from apt and snap, and installed just using apt-get, and now the plex container is visible using `docker ps -a`.

Comment: Did you found solution of your problem? As stated in ["Can I answer my own question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) - it's OK to accept your own answer

Answer (score 0):

To Just answer the question, there is also a way to identify the container id without using `docker ps`. You have to try deleting the image on which the container is created.

In your case you have to give `docker rmi plexinc/pms-docker`. If there is a container associated with this image, then you will get an error message like below:

```
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "plexinc/pms-docker" (must force) - container 92203921146d is using its referenced image f123as324ad
```

Here `92203921146d` is your conatiner ID.